# Join two tables in pandas with some conditions in columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

| Num | Algo | Distance | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 525 | M | 25 | Good |
| 524 | M | 28 | Good |
| 523 | M | 30 | Good |
| 522 | M | 75 | Good |

| Num | Algo | Distance | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 525 | T | 25 | Good |
| 524 | T | 28 | Bad |
| 520 | T | 98 | Good |

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Num' : [525, 524, 523, 522], 'Algo' : [M, M, M, M], 'Distance' : [25, 28, 30, 75], 'Result' : ['Good', 'Good', 'Good', 'Good']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Num' : [525, 524, 520], 'Algo' : [T, T, T], 'Distance' : [25, 28, 98], 'Result' : ['Good', 'Bad', 'Good']})
```

I have two dataframes as above and I want to join/merge them in the way as below (I tried different joins in pandas but it does not work as I want to):

| Num | Algo | Distance | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 525 | M, T | 25 | Good |
| 524 | M, T | 28 | Good |
| 523 | M | 30 | Good |
| 522 | M | 75 | Good |
| 520 | T | 98 | Good |

Also, I want to give priority to the `df_1['Result']` while joining as it can be seen I used `'Good'` for `'Num' = 524`.

Comment: in the result column, you only have Good or Bad? and the aggregation would be for equal Num and Distance?

Comment: In most cases, it is Good or Bad, but sometimes it can be both Good, Bad in the same row. Distance is always the same in two dataframes if the Num is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` after `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
new_df = df.groupby(["Num", "Distance"], 
                    as_index=False, 
                    sort=False).agg({"Algo" : ", ".join, 
                                     "Result" : "first"})
```

Output:

```
   Num  Distance  Algo Result
0  525        25  M, T   Good
1  524        28  M, T   Good
2  523        30     M   Good
3  522        75     M   Good
4  520        98     T   Good
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `merge`:

```
output = df_1.merge(df_2, on=["Num", "Distance"], how="outer")

#concat Algo columns from both dfs to a string
output["Algo"] = output["Algo_x"].fillna("").str.cat(output["Algo_y"].fillna(""), sep=", ").str.strip().str.strip(",")

#combine Result column using df_2 data only when df_1 is NaN
output["Result"] = output[["Result_x", "Result_y"]].ffill(axis=0)["Result_x"]
output = output[["Num", "Algo", "Distance", "Result"]]

>>> output
   Num  Algo  Distance Result
0  525  M, T        25   Good
1  524  M, T        28   Good
2  523     M        30   Good
3  522     M        75   Good
4  520     T        98   Good
```